# Option breaklinks doesn't actually break links pandoc

Tags: hyperref, links

```
\usepackage[
  breaklinks=true,
  unicode=true,
  urlcolor = blue,
  colorlinks = true,
  citecolor = blue,
  linkcolor = blue]{hyperref}
```

From what I've read, that should work. The other options *do* work. Nonetheless, the links do not break. Some of them walk clear off the page.

I'm using pandoc to generate the PDFs/LaTeX. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: doea pandoc runs latex or pdflatex?

Comment: @Herbert pandoc is just a mark-up language converter (though I've never got good results with it). Rayne must be running pdflatex or latex himself afterwards, though it would be worth knowing which one, since I have witnessed inconsistent results.

Comment: @Rayne: when it runs latex then you have to load package `breaklinks` after `hyperref`.

Comment: I meant package `breakurl`

Comment: @breakurl, @frabjous: I'm using markdown2pdf which uses pdflatex.

Comment: @Rayne maybe you could add an example of the `.tex` output so we can see where it's going wrong.